# User profiles in yum Repository Definition Files

Tags: yum

I have a host where the `yum.repos.d` directory contains a yum repository definition file that has a password protected repository and so has a plain text username and password.

This is not a big deal since this host does not have user accounts other than the administrator with sudo privileges.  However, I had the urge to make this file readable to root only, and I realized right away I couldn't do that:

```
Error: Error accessing file for config file://///etc/yum.repos.d/myrepo.repo
```

Which makes sense, but now I am curious if yum was designed to allow something like user profiles.

How can I have a repository configuration file which is only loaded under a certain user?  If this is not possible, does that mean that all users of a system must share all the repository definitions?  If I had a private repository for which I did not want to share the password, am I forced to delete that repository definition file after using the repository?

Answer (score -1):

> How can I have a repository configuration file which is only loaded
>   under a certain user?

For that you can use , user permissions. If you have two users and that configuration file should not allowed for that user then you dont give read & execute permissions to other users.

Comment: Setting the read permissions results in every user receiving the error I mentioned in my question whenever they run any yum command without sudo.

Comment: yes that means those particular updates/applications are not available , you can ignore that error.

Comment: I could, but... Maybe you're a bigger man than me.

Comment: @EdSaito what didnt get you ??

Comment: Well, I don't get how it doesn't bother you.  "To each its own".  I didn't downvote you by the way.

Comment: @EdSaito 1. dont care about down votes. 2.let me explain , if you are unable to access any repos link means that repo will no longer provides updates/applications.so those users who might get the error cant get updates from those repos in that file. so no problem.anything else ?

Comment: You're a good guy Raja, and you're right that the updates will be unavailable. The problem is you are providing a hack when I'm looking for a best practice.  One day I'll take the time to find out how the designers of yum intended private repositories to work in a multi-login environment.

Comment: @EdSaito my Friend ,  I am always happy to help you with what I know. Thank you.